# Yii: Getting name and image using cdbciteria

Tags: php, yii

I want to retrieve data from my database using `CDbcriteria`. I want to get the `name` and `image` of the last 4 Ngos from my `Ngo` table.

```
<?php
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->limit = 4;
$Criteria->order = "id DESC";
$Criteria->select = "id, ngo_name, image";
$Ngos =Ngo::model()->findAll($Criteria);
?>

<div class="row">
<h3>NGO's</h3>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
   <img src="<?php 
   foreach ( (array)$Ngos as $Ngo)
   {
       echo '$Ngo->image';
   }
   ?>"
<div class="caption">
<h3><?php
foreach ( (array)$Ngos as $Ngo)
   {
       echo '$Ngo->ngo_name';
   }
?></h3>
<a href="ngo-profile.php"> <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">View Profile</button></a>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? check application log.

Comment: not getting any error, $Ngo->ngo_name got printed on my screen 3 times and i cant show the image and name of the ngo.

Answer (score 1):

just remove single quotes around the variable `$Ngo->image` and `$Ngo->ngo_name` or use double quotes instead.

Comment: thanks for the help, i am able to display the ngo_name but unable to display th image, what could be the problem..??

Comment: What value does the image hold? If it's an HTML tag you won't see it.